# Convert 8bit MIME message to quoted-printable

Tags: email, mime, quoted-printable, 8-bit

What is the easiest way to convert a MIME e-mail containing raw 8bit parts to a RFC822 compliant message containing only 7bit parts ?
The parts have to be automatically converted to "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable".

My app is developed in Java. But a command-line tool would be great. I tried reformime but this tool seems buggy and doesn't rewrite message properly :-(

Thanks for any help,
Olivier

Answer (score 2):

JavaMail seems like a good solution.  Create a `MimeMessage` from your file, find the body parts whose content transfer encodings you want to change, call `MimeBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable")`, and write the resulting message out via `MimeMessage.writeTo()`.

Something along the lines of this:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties());
MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(new FileInputStream(msgfile));
// assuming we know that it's a multipart; otherwise, check Content-Type first...
MimeMultipart multi = (MimeMultipart) mm.getContent();
for (int i = 0; i < multi.getCount(); i++) {
    MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) multi.getBodyPart(i);
    mbp.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");
}
mm.saveChanges();
mm.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(outfile));
```

Note that `MimeMessage` by default will reset the `Message-ID` header when you've made changes to the message.  If you don't want this, override `MimeMessage.updateMessageID()` to a no-op.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Modifying a JavaMail's MimeMessage object doesn't work properly with nested Multiparts. With your solution, some parts are updated but some are not. I think it's a well-known problem with JavaMail (see: http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/blog/java/java-mail/removing-attachments-with-javamail/).

Comment: My sample code doesn't handle nested multiparts; it's just a guideline to show you the functions you might want to use.  Have you actually written a recursive program that exhibits the issues mentioned in the article?  Because messages parsed from a stream shouldn't have that issue...